# Joystick of StandardAssets is not displayed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I attempted to display joystick by referring to various websites.
The platform of the build is Android, which has already been set up.

I drag **MobileSingleStickControl** to Hierarchy.
Game objects are generated but joystick and jump buttons are not displayed.

There is also an EventSystem.
Canvas is active, but joystick and jump button are inactive.
I try to make it active, but I can not change it.

Why can not I? Anyone please reply.

Comment: It may be based off of which platform you are targeting. Open up the build options and target android.

Comment: Yes. The target of Platform has already been set to android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I installed all of StandardAssets, joysticks are appeared.
Perhaps the script for manipulating the joystick was not included in the project.